# Configure a timeout on /actuator/health

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

We are using the basic Health actuator to verify the health of our service and it works great. Unfortunately, it sometimes take a really long time to return (due to our environment, not the actuator itself). Short of writing our own HealthIndicator, is there a way to set a timeout specifically for the health actuator? A timeout shorter of course than the one we have on Tomcat for all the other endpoints in the application.

Comment: If some HTTP requests get stuck due to your environment, having nothing to do with the actuator, shouldn't you set the timouts on the client side?

Comment: @dbaltor thank you for the comment but this is one of those corporate place where I don't control much except the code we output.  Client is currently killing our app because it is timing out but is not reporting anything to anyone. i would like our app to timeout before the client does to have proper logs.